# What happens in this Swift code

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums, switch-statement

I am looking at this code that creates an enum and a dictionary that uses the enum and later dose a switch on the dictionary.

This is from a solution to Stanford CS193P calculator lessons. One of the cases in the enum contains this code.

```
case binaryOperation(Double, Double) -> Double, (String, String) -> String
```

one of the definitions in the dictionary is this:

```
"*" : Operation.binaryOperation(*, {$0 + "*" + $1})
```

The dictionary contains similar definitions for adding, subtracting, and dividing.

This calculator works fine. The correct answer is displayed and a description of the input is also shown in a second line.  I am not sure though it is calculating the correct answer.

How does swift know to take the arguments $0 and $1 from the second parameter and use them in the first parameter?

I hope this question makes sense.  There is a lot more code involved that I have not shown.

Comment: You mean `case binaryOperation((Double, Double) -> Double, (String, String) -> String)`, right? (note the outer parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

In `Operation.binaryOperation(*, {$0 + "*" + $1})`
the first parameter (the `*`) is a function, with e.g. this definition:
`func *(x: Double, y: Double) -> Double` 
so it's conform with the `(Double, Double) -> Double` definition above.

Second parametr is closure (in-line function) which uses two anonymous parameters $0 and $1 (Swift knows that, these are strings, because there is `(String, String) -> String` definition), and return string.

In swift, you can use $x syntax, to address parameters by position.

You can try to replace the first parametr with inline-function 
eg `{$0 * $1}` 
which is reduced version of `{return $0 * $1}`

Or with function:
`Operation.binaryOperation(multiply, {$0 + "*" + $1})`

`func multiply(x: Double, y: Double) -> Double {
  return x * y
}`